# Finding the State Table for a Synchronous Sequential Circuit

Tags: digital-logic

I'm learning about circuits in my ECE class and want to make sure that I have the correct table. I am working with D flip-flops and T flip-flops in this circuit. I want to make sure that I have the right table and, if I don't, what I did wrong here.

Thanks!

By the way, my answer is only the table. The stuff above and below it are for different problems.

[image: This is the circuit.]
[image: Here is my current table.]

Comment: Correct only. Proceed with it

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi, There are a few bugs, marked on the drawing in color. Think green :)